I want on scrolling my prevoius voice should stop and only current page voice play in my flutter page view builder and i'm using audio players
I'm working on sound social media app and i'm using audioplayers package ...But the problem is when i scroll the page the voice dont stop and every voices play the previous one and the current one plays at the same time ..Should stop the prevoius voices...Here's my code i'm using this in page view.builder
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:simple_waveform_progressbar/simple_waveform_progressbar.dart';
import 'package:social_notes/resources/colors.dart';

import 'package:social_notes/screens/home_screen/provider/filter_provider.dart';

class CustomProgressPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomProgressPlayer(
      {Key? key,
      required this.noteUrl,
      required this.height,
      required this.width,
      required this.mainWidth,
      required this.mainHeight,
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
      this.size = 35,
      this.isComment = false,
      this.isMainPlayer = false,
      this.commentId,
      this.postId,
      this.playedCounter,
      this.pageController,
      this.currentIndex,
      this.waveColor})
      : super(key: key);

  final String noteUrl;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double mainWidth;
  final double mainHeight;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  double size;
  int? playedCounter;
  Color? waveColor;
  bool isComment;
  String? commentId;
  String? postId;
  bool isMainPlayer;
  PageController? pageController;

  int? currentIndex;
  @override
  State<CustomProgressPlayer> createState() => _CustomProgressPlayerState();
}

class _CustomProgressPlayerState extends State<CustomProgressPlayer> {
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  String? _cachedFilePath;
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  double _playbackSpeed = 1.0; // Default playback speed
  PlayerState? _playerState;
  // StreamSubscription? _durationSubscription;
  // StreamSubscription? _positionSubscription;
  // StreamSubscription? _playerCompleteSubscription;
  // StreamSubscription? _playerStateChangeSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initPlayer();
    // _initStreams();
    super.initState();
  }

  
  initPlayer() async {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    _audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);
    _audioPlayer.setSourceUrl(widget.noteUrl);
    _playerState = _audioPlayer.state;

    // Check if the file is already cached
    DefaultCacheManager().getFileFromCache(widget.noteUrl).then((file) {
      if (file != null && file.file.existsSync()) {
        _cachedFilePath = file.file.path;
      }
    });
    _audioPlayer.getDuration().then(
          (value) => setState(() {
            duration = value!;
          }),
        );
    _audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition().then(
          (value) => setState(() {
            position = value!;
          }),
        );
    _audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        duration = event;
      });
    });
    _audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        position = event;
      });
    });

    _audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.listen((state) {
      if (widget.isMainPlayer) {
        if (widget.pageController!.page != widget.currentIndex!.toDouble()) {
          playPause();
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _playerState = PlayerState.stopped;
            _isPlaying = false;
            position = Duration.zero;
          });
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _playerState = PlayerState.stopped;
          _isPlaying = false;
          position = Duration.zero;
        });
      }
    });

    _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = state;
      });
    });

    if (widget.isMainPlayer) {
      playPause();
    }
  
  }

  void _updatePlayedComment() {
    if (widget.isComment) {
      int updateCommentCounter = widget.playedCounter ?? 0;
      updateCommentCounter++;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('notes')
          .doc(widget.postId)
          .collection('comments')
          .doc(widget.commentId)
          .update({'playedComment': updateCommentCounter});
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _audioPlayer.dispose();
    // if (_playerState == PlayerState.playing) {
    //   _audioPlayer.stop();
    // }
    // _durationSubscription?.cancel();
    // _positionSubscription?.cancel();
    // _playerCompleteSubscription?.cancel();
    // _playerStateChangeSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void playPause() async {
    if (_audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.playing) {
      await _audioPlayer.pause();
      setState(() {
        _isPlaying = false;
      });
    } else {
      if (_cachedFilePath != null) {
        await _audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate(_playbackSpeed);
        await _audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(_cachedFilePath!));
        _updatePlayedComment();
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = true;
        });
      } else {
        DefaultCacheManager().downloadFile(widget.noteUrl).then((fileInfo) {
          if (fileInfo.file.existsSync()) {
            _cachedFilePath = fileInfo.file.path;
            _audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate(_playbackSpeed);
            _audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(_cachedFilePath!));
            setState(() {
              _isPlaying = true;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Duration duration = Duration.zero;
  Duration position = Duration.zero;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // log('Waveform: $doubleWaveformData');
    // checkAutoPlay();
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: widget.mainHeight,
          width: widget.mainWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(55),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              if (widget.isMainPlayer)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: playPause,
                    child: Consumer<FilterProvider>(
                        builder: (context, filterPro, _) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:
                              filterPro.selectedFilter.contains('Close Friends')
                                  ? greenColor
                                  : widget.waveColor ?? primaryColor,
                         
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        ),
                       
                        child: _isPlaying
                            ? Icon(
                                Icons.pause_outlined,
                                color: whiteColor,
                                size: 20,
                              )
                            : Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.play_arrow,
                                    color: whiteColor,
                                    size: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                )
              else
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: playPause,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: whiteColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      ),
                      // onPressed: playPause,
                      child: _isPlaying
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.pause,
                              color: widget.backgroundColor,
                              size: widget.size,
                            )
                          : Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.play_arrow,
                                  color: widget.backgroundColor,
                                  size: widget.size,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              SizedBox(
                  height: widget.height,
                  width: widget.width,
                  child:
                    
                      Consumer<FilterProvider>(
                          builder: (context, filterPro, _) {
                    return WaveformProgressbar(
                      color: filterPro.selectedFilter.contains('Close Friends')
                          ? greenColor.withOpacity(0.5)
                          : widget.isMainPlayer
                              ? primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5)
                              : widget.waveColor!.withOpacity(0.5),
                    
                      progressColor:
                          filterPro.selectedFilter.contains('Close Friends')
                              ? greenColor
                              : widget.isMainPlayer
                                  ? primaryColor
                                  : widget.waveColor ?? primaryColor,
                      
                      progress: position.inSeconds / duration.inSeconds,
                      onTap: (progress) {
                        if (_cachedFilePath != null) {
                          Duration seekPosition = Duration(
                              seconds: (progress * duration.inSeconds).round());
                          // Duration seekPosition =
                          //     Duration(seconds: progress.toInt());
                          _audioPlayer.seek(seekPosition);
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  })
               
                  ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Consumer<FilterProvider>(builder: (context, filterPro, _) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    position.inSeconds == 0
                        ? Text(
                            '${duration.inSeconds ~/ 60}:${duration.inSeconds % 60}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: fontFamily,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: filterPro.selectedFilter
                                      .contains('Close Friends')
                                  ? greenColor
                                  : widget.waveColor ?? primaryColor,
                            ),
                          )
                        : Text(
                            '${position.inSeconds ~/ 60}:${position.inSeconds % 60}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: fontFamily,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: filterPro.selectedFilter
                                      .contains('Close Friends')
                                  ? greenColor
                                  : widget.waveColor ?? primaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                    if (widget.waveColor == null)
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (_playbackSpeed == 1.0) {
                              _playbackSpeed = 1.5;
                            } else if (_playbackSpeed == 1.5) {
                              _playbackSpeed = 2.0;
                            } else {
                              _playbackSpeed = 1.0;
                            }
                            // Set playback speed if audio is already playing
                            if (_isPlaying) {
                              _audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate(_playbackSpeed);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        child: Consumer<FilterProvider>(
                            builder: (context, filterPro, _) {
                          return Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 4, vertical: 4),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: filterPro.selectedFilter
                                        .contains('Close Friends')
                                    ? greenColor
                                    : primaryColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                            child: Text(
                              '${_playbackSpeed}X',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: whiteColor,
                                fontFamily: fontFamily,
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              })
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




